# how to parse "2013:11:21 15:11:04+02:00" to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I would like to parse 2013:11:21 15:11:04+02:00 to DateTime

I tried

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2013:11:21 15:11:04+02:00", "yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:sszzz", null)
```

but it throws System.FormatException

Comment: just parse it to a DateTimeOffset first.

Comment: What’s `+02:00`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format should include `HH` instead of `hh` since you are using a 24 hour clock:

`DateTime.ParseExact("2013:11:21 15:11:04+02:00", "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:sszzz", null)`